# str_match based on vector with count issue

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I havent got a reprex but my data are stored in a csv file

https://transcode.geo.data.gouv.fr/services/5e2a1fbefa4268bc25628f27/feature-types/drac:site?format=CSV&projection=WGS84

```
library(readr)
bzh_sites <- read_csv("site.csv")
```

I want to count row based on characters matching (column NATURE)

```
pattern<-c("allée|aqueduc|architecture|atelier|bas|carrière|caveau|chapelle|château|chemin|cimetière|coffre|dépôt|dolmen|eau|église|enceinte|enclos|éperon|espace|exploitation|fanum|ferme|funéraire|groupe|habitat|maison|manoir|menhir|monastère|motte|nécropole|occupation|organisation|parcellaire|pêcherie|prieuré|production|rue|sépulture|stèle|thermes|traitement|tumulus|villa")


 test2 <-  bzh_sites %>%
  drop_na(NATURE) %>%
   group_by(NATURE = str_match( NATURE, pattern )) %>%
   summarise(n = n())
```

gives me :

```
NATURE  n
1   allée   176
2   aqueduc 73
3   architecture    68
4   atelier 200
```

AND another test with the same data (NATURE)

```
pattern <- c("allée|aqueduc|architecture|atelier")

test2 <-  bzh_sites %>%
 drop_na(NATURE) %>%
 group_by(NATURE = str_match( NATURE, pattern )) %>%
 summarise(n = n())
```

gives me :

```
NATURE    n
1   allée   178
2   aqueduc 74
3   architecture    79
4   atelier 248
```

I have no idea about the différences of count.

Comment: I would first find out which row differs using both the pattern. Run `bzh_sites %>%
  drop_na(NATURE) %>%
  group_by(NATURE = str_match( NATURE, pattern )) %>%
  filter(NATURE == 'allée')` using both the pattern and store it in `df1` and `df2`. Then do `anti_join(df2, df1)` to find out rows which exist in `df2` and not in `df1`.

Comment: Is `bzh_sites` available via link?

Comment: @markhogue I give you a link

Comment: @RonakShah I give you a link to my data.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find out where the discrepancy is for first group i.e `"allée"`. This is what I found :

```
library(stringr)

pattern1<-c("allée|aqueduc|architecture|atelier|bas|carrière|caveau|chapelle|château|chemin|cimetière|coffre|dépôt|dolmen|eau|église|enceinte|enclos|éperon|espace|exploitation|fanum|ferme|funéraire|groupe|habitat|maison|manoir|menhir|monastère|motte|nécropole|occupation|organisation|parcellaire|pêcherie|prieuré|production|rue|sépulture|stèle|thermes|traitement|tumulus|villa")

#Get indices where 'allée' is found using pattern1
ind1 <- which(str_match(bzh_sites$NATURE, pattern1 )[, 1] == 'allée')

pattern2 <- c("allée|aqueduc|architecture|atelier")
#Get indices where 'allée' is found using pattern1
ind2 <- which(str_match(bzh_sites$NATURE, pattern2)[, 1] == 'allée')

#Indices which are present in ind2 but absent in ind1
setdiff(ind2, ind1)
#[1]  3093 10400

#Get corresponding text
temp <- bzh_sites$NATURE[setdiff(ind2, ind1)]
temp
#[1] "dolmen allée couverte"           "coffre funéraire allée couverte"
```

What happens when we use `pattern1` and `pattern2` on `temp`

```
str_match(temp, pattern1)
#         [,1]    
#[1,] "dolmen"
#[2,] "coffre"

str_match(temp, pattern2)

#       [,1]   
#[1,] "allée"
#[2,] "allée"
```

As we can see using `pattern1` certain values are classified in another group since they occur first in the string hence we have a mismatch.

A similar explanation can be given for mismatches in other groups.

---

`str_match` only returns first match, to get all the matches in pattern we can use `str_match_all`

```
table(unlist(str_match_all(bzh_sites$NATURE, pattern1)))

#       allée      aqueduc architecture      atelier          bas 
#         178           76           79          252           62 
#    carrière       caveau     chapelle      château       chemin 
#          46           35          226          205          350 
#   cimetière       coffre        dépôt       dolmen          eau 
#         275          155          450          542          114 
#      église     enceinte       enclos       éperon       space 
#         360          655          338          114          102 
#exploitation        fanum        ferme    funéraire       groups 
#        1856           38          196         1256          295 
#     habitat       maison       manoir       menhir    monastère 
#        1154           65          161         1036           31 
#       motte    nécropole   occupation organisation  parcellaire 
#         566          312         5152           50          492 
#    pêcherie      prieuré   production          rue    sépulture 
#          69           66          334           44          152 
#       stèle      thermes   traitement      tumulus        villa 
#         651           50          119         1232          225
```

Comment: Great answer. So how can i get the right count of row matching each word ? str_match is not a good solution.

Comment: `str_match` returns first match. You can use `str_match_all` to find all the words in the string. See output of `str_match_all(temp, pattern1)`.

Comment: str_match_all returns an error : Column `NATURE` can't be used as a grouping variable because it's a list

Comment: You can use `table(unlist(str_match_all(bzh_sites$NATURE, pattern1)))`

Comment: Do you consider that my question is useful or clear ?

Comment: Yes, it is but as you might know now that it was difficult to guess what was happening without the data.